# Updating the list object passed to the adapter to create a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to update the contents of the list object which has been passed to the adapter inorder to create a GridView. Here is the code:

```
 public class GameActivity extends Activity {
List<String> nums;
GridView sudoku_grid;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);
    sudoku_grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.sudoku_grid);
    nums= Arrays.asList("1","2","3","5","7","8","2","3","1","9","3","3","1");
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,nums);
    sudoku_grid.setAdapter(adapter);
}

    public void trial(View view)
    {
        Runnable r=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                nums.add("7");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }};
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
```

trial() executes every time a button is clicked. As soon as the thread in trial() starts, instead of the contents being updated, it results in starting the previous activity. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `nums` object again to the adapter.
Create a `class` that `extends` `ArrayAdapter<String>`
as follows:

```
class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    List<String> nums;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context,int itemID,List<String> nums){
        this.nums=nums;
    }

    @ovverride
    public int getCount() {
        return nums.size();
    }

    public void changeObjects(List<String> nums){
        this.nums=nums;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //.... Implement own code
    }

}
```

Let me know if there is any more problem or queries.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not run `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your own thread. It needs to run on UI Thread.

Try:

```
GameActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    ...
```

instead.